# Django REST - How to create a non-model serializer?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

Firstly I want to say I'm a newbie to Django.

I was wondering if is it possible to create a non-ModelSerializer which serialize existant model based serializers ?

In *serializers.py*, I already have this :

```
class MapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Map
      fields = ('id', 'name')


class GrenadeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Grenade
       fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I want here a new serializer which allows to display a JSON like that :

```
{
"maps": {
    "map": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "dust2"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "inferno"
        }
    ]
},

"grenades": {
    "grenade": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "flashbang"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "smoke"
        }
    ]
}}
```

I need something like this, even if I know the following structure isn't correct :

```
class MyNewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    maps = MapSerializer(many=True)
    grenades = GrenadeSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    field = ('maps', 'grenades')
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check out http://drewrygh.com/blog/combining-models-django-rest-framework/

Comment: Hi fasouto, thanks for sharing this link. I was looking for a way to do this in my serializers.py file